# Is the denominator in $\frac{t^\epsilon}{\log\log t}$ worthless?

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

In context of analytic numbertheory I am faced with the problem to give an asymptotic estimation for
$$C\frac{\vert t\vert^\epsilon}{\log\log \vert t\vert}$$ for a constant $C>0$ and an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$.

It's no problem to see that $$C\frac{\vert t\vert^\epsilon}{\log\log \vert t\vert}=O(\vert t\vert^\epsilon)$$
which makes this denominator $\log \log t$ quite worthless. Now I wonder, if there is any better asymptotic than that?
Can we acutally make any use of this denominator? Since we know that $\log t=O(t^\epsilon)$ and therefore $\log\log t=O(t^\epsilon)$ I dont think that there are any better estimations, but I am not so sure about it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What do you mean by asymptotic estimation? ${|t|}^\epsilon/(\log\log |t|)$ is already a perfectly good asymptotic estimation!

Comment: But is $\vert t\vert^\epsilon /\log\log \vert t\vert$ really "better" than $\vert t\vert^\epsilon$, since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary anyways? Because otherwise I'd like just to simplify this expression

Comment: Well, if $\epsilon$ is a fixed arbitrary number then of course there's a difference. I doubt there's a way to simplify the expression.

Comment: ye you're right there's no need to write the $\log \log t$ in